# How to set flag in facebook init function javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a sample code:

```
function initFB() {
    var flag;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'zzzzzz', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

        var flag;
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                flag = 1;
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                flag = 2;
            } else {
                flag = 3;
            }
        });    
    };
    return flag;
}

var flag = initFB();
alert(flag);
```

=> result is `undefined` , Can't set flag in facebook function ?, If not, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest you to do is to use a callback (probably anonymous), as the functions `fbAsyncInit` and `getLoginStatus` functions are both asynchronous (which means that they won't return something right away - they have to call facebook first, and after they've done so, they call their own callback (the `function() {` part)).

```
function initFB(callback) {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'zzzzzz', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            var flag;
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                flag = 1;
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                flag = 2;
            } else {
                flag = 3;
            }
            callback(flag);
            /* This will call the anonymous function specified as 
               "callback" with a parameter of whatever is in the 
               "flag" variable. */
        });    
    };
}

/* Here we use an anonymous function as a callback of 
   when getLoginStatus has gotten it's return value */
initFB(function(flag) {
    alert(flag); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a scope and sync problem. The second time you define "flag" it´s only visible inside of the fbAsyncInit function, no connection to the "flag" variable on the outside. Also, the code in the fbAsyncInit function will get called later, when "flag" on the outside already got returned.

Comment: Would it work to send "flag" from inside initFB() to the second function? Example:
function initFB() {
    var flag;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(flag) {

Comment: It's *also* an async problem as both `fbAsyncInit` and `getLoginStatus` are asynchronous, and therefore flag wouldn't have a value as soon as `initFB()` was called.

Comment: you would have to define "flag" OUTSIDE of every function. and don´t redefine it with "var". but you only have access AFTER the fbAsyncInit call.

Comment: the answer of h2ooo.... is better than mine and presents a nice solution too. in fact the best one, as it does not need global vars.